# How can I extract the URL session ID and replace the Old one with iMacros

Tags: macros, imacros

First Thank you for this Community, I'm new here and I'll like to help everyone if I can.

I hope that is sufficiently well explained:

1. I log into a webpage and I get a random ID (Example) **8888888888**:

http://whatever/index.php?page=overview&session=**8888888888**

2. I need to grab the random session ID: **8888888888** becouse every login I have a NEW ID and I want to REPLACE the OLD one in the macro code. ( maybe with a VAR ? )

Example:

**First, I'll Log in, I get the random ID.**

Random ID example:
http://whatever/index.php?page=overview&session=**8888888888**

Ok, now I run this macro:

```
SET !VAR1 {{!URLCURRENT}}
TAB T=1
URL GOTO={{!VAR1}}
```

Now I need to 
GET session ID: **8888888888** and need to **replace the OLD login ID**: **XXXX** in the rest of the macro, so I don't have to write it manually for the macro to run, every time I log in again with the new ID.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Fleet
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:index.php?page=flotten2&session=XXXX ATTR=NAME:ship210 CONTENT=41
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:index.php?page=flotten2&session=XXXX ATTR=VALUE:continue
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:index.php?page=flotten3&session=XXXX ATTR=NAME:system CONTENT=191
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:index.php?page=flotten3&session=XXXX ATTR=NAME:planet CONTENT=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:index.php?page=flotten3&session=XXXX ATTR=VALUE:continue
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:index.php?page=flottenversand&session=XXXX ATTR=VALUE:continue
WAIT SECONDS=190
```

So It will look like this automatically every login with the new ID:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Fleet
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:index.php?page=flotten2&session=8888888888 ATTR=NAME:ship210 CONTENT=41
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:index.php?page=flotten2&session=8888888888 ATTR=VALUE:continue
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:index.php?page=flotten3&session=8888888888 ATTR=NAME:system CONTENT=191
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:index.php?page=flotten3&session=8888888888 ATTR=NAME:planet CONTENT=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:index.php?page=flotten3&session=8888888888 ATTR=VALUE:continue
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:index.php?page=flottenversand&session=8888888888 ATTR=VALUE:continue
WAIT SECONDS=190
```

Actually, I'm replacing the old id with the new one Manually... so I'm starting to get bored :D

Thank you in advance and ask me if you have any comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
SET !VAR1 {{!URLCURRENT}}
TAB T=1
URL GOTO={{!VAR1}}

SET id EVAL("'{{!URLCURRENT}}'.match(/session=(\w+)/)[1];")

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Fleet
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:index.php?page=flotten2&session={{id}} ATTR=NAME:ship210 CONTENT=41
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:index.php?page=flotten2&session={{id}} ATTR=VALUE:continue
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:index.php?page=flotten3&session={{id}} ATTR=NAME:system CONTENT=191
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:index.php?page=flotten3&session={{id}} ATTR=NAME:planet CONTENT=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:index.php?page=flotten3&session={{id}} ATTR=VALUE:continue
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:index.php?page=flottenversand&session={{id}} ATTR=VALUE:continue
WAIT SECONDS=190
```